# How to add items (object) to array in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

In my firestore collection named "User" I have one array called "Comments". Every time when user tap on submit button I need to append this object to that particular array.

My array name structure :

```
User (Collection Name) --> DocID(UserName) --> Comments (Array key)
```

I need to append my all object to my Comments key.

My comments obj will be:

```
{

Nickname = "Mike dab",
Subscribed = "No",
FriendsListId = [1,2,3,4],
EnemyListId = [2,3],
Alive= "yes"

}
```

Here is the code i am using for upload to firestore :

```
firestore()
    .collection("User")
    .doc("Mike") 
    .set({
        "Comments": [
            {

            }
        ]

    })
    .then((ref) => { 
        alert("updated successfully !")
    });
```

Each time when I add data. It should be add  to my "Comments" array as index object. How can I do that. I am new bie, any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: @Doug Stevenson Yes, i saw that. But as per my example. I am not able to append that correct value.

Comment: Then you might want to ask a new question that describes in more detail exactly what isn't working the way you expect.  What you're showing right now looks incomplete.  I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example